# Get DLL from EXE file

Tags: ollydbg, malware, dll, dll-injection

I am trying to reverse engineer an DLL that is loaded from a EXE.

I don't have the DLL file. I just have an executable file that injects the DLL into a certain process.

When I try using ollydbg or similar software, I could not find it.

Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to dump the DLL file it injects!

Comment: Why can't you find it?